# Arbitrary "cannot identify image file" Error

Tags: python

When running this code, I sometimes get the error: PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001CDD408E250>

It happens during an arbitrary epoch, and sometimes there is no error at all, even tho I changed nothing. Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
   from keras.models import load_model, Sequential
    from keras.layers import Conv2D,Flatten,Activation,Dense,MaxPooling2D,Dropout
    from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, img_to_array
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(64,64,3),activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))         
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))                                                                                                         
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu')) 
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) 
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu')) 
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))  
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
    
    model.summary()
    
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy',  metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    train_dir = 'dog-vs-cat-classification/train'
    test_dir = 'dog-vs-cat-classification/test'
    
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    trainRescale = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)
    
    testRescale = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    
    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dog-vs-cat-classification/train/', target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'binary')
    
    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dog-vs-cat-classification/test/', target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'binary')
    
    model.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch = 8, epochs = 20, validation_data = test_set)
    model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')
    model.save('model_keras.h5')
    
    testImage = os.listdir('dog-vs-cat-classification/test/')
    
    for image in testImage:
        img = Image.open('dog-vs-cat-classification/test/' + image)
        img = img_to_array(img)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        result = model.predict(img)
        if result[0][0] >=0.5:
            prediction = 'dog'
        else:
            prediction = 'cat'    
    
    print("image", image, "is a: ", prediction)
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the full error traceback message, instead of asking us to guess where the error happened...

Comment: The error have 6000 too many characters to post, even after I remove part of the file location which is the same for all. What can I do? If I give the Python file that had an error and which line, then the underlined part below that?

Comment: At least tell us which specific line of code throws the exception.

Comment: This is the line where it stops:
model.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch = 8, epochs = 40, validation_data = test_set)

tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1816] UNKNOWN: UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000018D734F9800>
Traceback (most recent call last):

    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
LAST error message:  
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000018D734F9800>
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1787]

Comment: It sounds like you have 1 corrupted img and since the data is being picked randomly it is not always going to be chosen. Try to find it by printing the path of the file when the error is thrown.

Comment: It would have to be maybe files, as it crashes every time I run it. [the first time it has run 70 epochs on occasion but all efforts after fail, and I've done 100 by now]

Comment: Tried a different data base and so far so good. The accuracy seems to be ~70 only. I'm running 70 epochs with batch size 32. Is that too few?

Comment: My test image selection is not random, I think 1 of. these is the line where I make it random?  testImage = os.listdir('dogs-vs-cats/test/')
Or
for image in testImage:
    img = Image.open('dogs-vs-cats/test/' + image)       How is that done?  Thanks.